# Kivy: GridLayout always goes left to right then down, can you go top to bottom then left to right?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm working on a relatively simple layout in Kivy, and want to display a series of buttons which get populated top to bottom of the screen, then when they reach the bottom, a new column is started from the top.

GridLayout appears to do what I want, but it always seems to go from left to right first, rather than top to bottom. I've check the official documentation and Google and can't seem to find a solution.

StackLayout does what I want with the "orientation: "tb-lr" command, however the button widths don't get fully scaled to fit the container when there's only one column which GridLayout does do and is required for this application.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not in a mistake, this feature is not implemented. However, you are free to implement your own layout using the `Layout` class (`kivy.uix.layout`).

Another possibility is subclassify `GridLayout` and overwrite a couple of methods to add the witgets from top to bottom:

> **Warning**
>
> The GridLayout class has major changes between Kivy 1.9 and Kivy 1.10. For this reason, the code works correctly on **Kivy 1.10.0** but not in previous versions (See comments).
>
> You must always **specify the number of rows** of the Layout.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button


def nmax(*args):
    # merge into one list
    args = [x for x in args if x is not None]
    return max(args)


def nmin(*args):
    # merge into one list
    args = [x for x in args if x is not None]
    return min(args)

class TBGridLayout(GridLayout):
    
    def _fill_rows_cols_sizes(self):
        cols, rows = self._cols, self._rows
        cols_sh, rows_sh = self._cols_sh, self._rows_sh
        cols_sh_min, rows_sh_min = self._cols_sh_min, self._rows_sh_min
        cols_sh_max, rows_sh_max = self._cols_sh_max, self._rows_sh_max

        # calculate minimum size for each columns and rows
        n_rows = len(rows)
        has_bound_y = has_bound_x = False
        for i, child in enumerate(reversed(self.children)):
            (shw, shh), (w, h) = child.size_hint, child.size
            shw_min, shh_min = child.size_hint_min
            shw_max, shh_max = child.size_hint_max
            col,  row = divmod(i, n_rows)

            # compute minimum size / maximum stretch needed
            if shw is None:
                cols[col] = nmax(cols[col], w)
            else:
                cols_sh[col] = nmax(cols_sh[col], shw)
                if shw_min is not None:
                    has_bound_x = True
                    cols_sh_min[col] = nmax(cols_sh_min[col], shw_min)
                if shw_max is not None:
                    has_bound_x = True
                    cols_sh_max[col] = nmin(cols_sh_max[col], shw_max)

            if shh is None:
                rows[row] = nmax(rows[row], h)
            else:
                rows_sh[row] = nmax(rows_sh[row], shh)
                if shh_min is not None:
                    has_bound_y = True
                    rows_sh_min[col] = nmax(rows_sh_min[col], shh_min)
                if shh_max is not None:
                    has_bound_y = True
                    rows_sh_max[col] = nmin(rows_sh_max[col], shh_max)
        self._has_hint_bound_x = has_bound_x
        self._has_hint_bound_y = has_bound_y
       
    def _iterate_layout(self, count):
        selfx = self.x
        padding_left = self.padding[0]
        padding_top = self.padding[1]
        spacing_x, spacing_y = self.spacing

        i = count - 1
        x = selfx + padding_left
        
        for col_width in self._cols:
            y = self.top - padding_top
            for row_height in self._rows:
                if i < 0:
                    break
                yield i, x, y - row_height, col_width, row_height
                i -=  1
                y -=  spacing_y + row_height
            x += col_width + spacing_x
            
# EXAMPLE OF USE    
class MainWindow(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.orientation = 'vertical'
        self.layout = TBGridLayout(rows=5)
        self.add_widget(self.layout)
        
        self.cont = 0
        self.add_widget(Button(text='Add Button',
                               size_hint = (1,  0.15),  
                               on_press= self.add_button))

        
    def add_button(self,  instance):
        self.cont += 1
        self.layout.add_widget(Button(text = 'Button' + str(self.cont)))

class ExampleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainWindow()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ExampleApp().run()
```

**Running example:**

[image]

**PD**: The code is just a quick example, it is tested but could contain a bug.

Comment: The code above runs (Linux Mint 18.1, Python 3.6) out of the box, but the buttons are arranged left to right then top to bottom.
[INFO              ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
[INFO              ] [Python      ] v3.6.1 (default, Apr 18 2017, 23:00:41) 
[GCC 5.4.1 20160904]

Comment: @Claudio Does this occur if you specify the number of rows?  I think you may be right, but it should only happen if you do not specify the number of rows. Best regards .

Comment: From the code: `self.layout = TBGridLayout(rows=5)` . There are only 5 rows generated, then the next column, but the order of the buttons is there left-right, top-down (not top-down, left-right).

Comment: @Claudio, You're right. I could not reproduce your problem because the code works correctly on kivy 1.10.0 (tested on Windows 10 and Kubuntu 16.04), but fails on previous versions (such as 1.9). I'll try to fix it as soon as I have time. Thanks for the warning.

Answer (score 0):

Use GridLayout but populate it with BoxLayouts instead of buttons. Orient each of these BoxLayouts vertically and populate the buttons inside.